# Trying to find frequent patterns in a sequence python

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching, sequence, apriori

I am trying to find frequent ( ordered or unordered) patterns in a column. The column contains numeric IDs. for eg:
s=[1 2 3 4 1 2 6 7 8 2 1 10 11]

Here 1 2 or 2 1 taking as a same case is the most frequent set.

Please help me to solve this problem, I could think of apriori, FP algorithms but I don't have any transaction, just a sequence.

Comment: What are the pattern set sizes?

Comment: of any size(2:N). I have millions of rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of business decisions you have to take before you will have a normal algorithm. The first and the most important decision is what size of the set do you want. Clearly if you have `{a, b, ... x}` is the most frequent set, then every subset (like `{a, x}` or `{c, d, y}` will be at least with the same frequency).

You need to know which one do you need (may be all or any). Also what would you do in case of these frequencies `{a, b}` with frequency 100 and `{a, c, d, e, f, g}` with frequency 20. Clearly the first one is more frequent, but the second is also pretty frequent and really long.

---

One way to approach this is to iterate over all 1 element subsequences and find their frequency. Then all 2 element and so on. Then create some weighted score which can be the frequency multiplied by some function based on the length of the sequence. Select the highest score.

Comment: I am trying to figure out all the frequent sets which come together(of whatever length), these are actually alarmIDs in which there is some correlation between the alarmIDs coming together, So after finding the frequent sets I want to predict further information using these frequent sets.

Comment: @NehaGoyal so just the the first part without creating a weighted score.

Comment: I am trying doing the same but won't it be too time taking? Is there no direct algorithm available ? @SalvadorDali

Comment: @NehaGoyal can you be more precise with your engineering terms? What do you mean by too much time, what is a direct algorithm? Based on my quick analysis it will take O(n^3 log n) time for a column of n elements. I have no idea what direct algorithm means

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a brute force approach.But it is not not efficient.It will be something like:

```
a) Calculate the powerset of the given sequence (it will be completed in exponential time). This will include duplicate occurrences of subsets as well.
b) Iterate over the subsets and calculate the frequency of each subset.
c) Sort in ascending order of the frequencies calculated in step (b) and pick the K smallest.
```